# WPF Stringformat is rounding up if .5 or above, but not rounding down

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I have a textbox bound to a double using stringformat {}{0:#,#} which in 50% of cases works fine:

1123456.123 comes out as 1,123,456.123 - Perfect! my problem lies when I try to put in .5 or more

1123456.5 comes out as 1123457  - What am I missing ???

Comment: I'm not able to repro your issue: `1123456.123` became `1,123,456` and `1123456.5` became `1,123,457` so for me it rounds up and down...

Comment: Figured it out! - its {}{0:#,#.#}